# Determine image content using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, minimagick

Is it possible to easily determine whether or not an image has any actual content beyond just transparency using ImageMagick?

The back story is that I am cropping a image with unknown content, but a known area map (think game skins). The area I'm cropping for part of this will either contain something or it won't. If it contains something, I need to do something with it. If it doesn't, I need to scrap it and move on. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "more than 100% transparency"? How can something be more than 100% transparent?

Comment: Hah, poor phrasing I suppose. Pardon. I was referring to any content at all vs simply all transparency. Great name, by the way, @ReticulatedSpline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a couple of ideas you could try, but I have not seen your images, so you will need to test them out.

Firstly, you could count the number of colours in the image, like this:

```
identify -format "%[k]" input.png
```

If there is only transparency, the number of colours will be 1, if there are other colours in the image, it will be greater than one. This cannot differentiate between a pure single colour image and a purely transparent image though. That may, or may not, be a problem. I don't speak Ruby, but I believe you access `k` like this in Ruby:

```
image["%[k]"]
```

Secondly, you could calculate the mean pixel colour of the image, like this:

```
identify -format "%[mean]" input.png
```

That will be zero in the case of a fully transparent image. However it will also be zero for a fully black image, which may or may not be a problem.

Both of these parameters can also be seen using

```
identify -verbose input.png
```

If you wanted a more robust test, for example to differentiate between a fully trasnparent image and a fully black image, you could use one of the tests above, and combine it with getting the value of a single pixel at top left of image to rule out the odd edge cases above, like this:

```
convert black.png -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:
black

convert transparent.png -format "%[pixel:p{0,0}]" info:
none
```

Another option would be to calculate the histogram, like this and see the colours:

```
convert input.png -format %c histogram:info:-
```

Comment: While I'm ultimately looking for a single step solution here, that may not exist using ImageMagick. To that end, this is one way to achieve what I'm looking for, so I'll accept this as the answer to this question. I really appreciate the help. If anyone else has another way to accomplish this more directly, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code:

```
def transparent? image
  solid_color = image['%[mean]'].to_i == 0 # transparent or solid color
  not_opaque = !image['%[opaque]'].to_bool # no transparency remaining
  solid_color && not_opaque
end
```

`image['%[mean]']` gives me 0 for as single color or full on transparency, as Mark Setchell mentioned. This got me half way. In order to determine if the single color is transparent or not, I used `image['%[opaque]']`. If this was "true", then it is a color. Otherwise, transparent. The `.to_bool` method simply takes the resulting boolean string and converts it into an actual boolean.

I hope this helps someone else! And thanks again for the significant start toward figuring this out, Mark!